# throw () after function declaration in c++ exception struct?

Tags: c++, exception, struct

Here is from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_exceptions_handling.htm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

struct MyException : public exception
{
  const char * what () const throw ()
  {
    return "C++ Exception";
  }
};
```

I understand the `const` after `what` means the function does not modify any
members of the struct, but what does the `throw()` at the end mean?

Comment: Tangential: given "C++ Exception" is function-local and has automatic storage, could what() throw `std::badalloc` if you were out of memory?

Comment: @rjfalconer why do you think that has automatic storage?  The unnamed pointer return value does, but the array?

Comment: Ah yes. I'm ignoring the return type. So same question then but for any arbitrary example where automatic storage is used: would that prohibit the use of such an exception specifier?

Answer (score 35):

It means it won't throw any exceptions. This is an important guarantee for a function like `what`, which is usually called in exception handling: you don't want another exception to be thrown while you're trying to handle one.

In C++11, you generally should use `noexcept` instead. The old throw specification is deprecated.

Answer (score 14):

`throw ()` is an exception specifier that declares that `what()` will never throw an exception. This is deprecated in C++11, however (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11). To specify that a function does not throw any exception, the `noexcept` keyword exists in C++11.

Answer (score 8):

> You can specify the type being thrown so that if it throws anything
>   but that type (e.g. `int`), then the function calls `std::unexpected`
>   instead of looking for a handler or calling `std::terminate`.
>
> In this case, it won't throw any exceptions, which is important for
>   `what()`.
>
> If this throw specifier is left empty with no type, this means that
>   `std::unexpected` is called for any exception. Functions with no throw
>   specifier (regular functions) never call `std::unexpected`, but follow
>   the normal path of looking for their exception handler.
>
> This is called *dynamic exception specifications* and it was common in
>   older code. It is considered deprecated.

See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/