# rewrite throw after function with noexcept

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I have heard that in `C++11` we should replace `throw` with `noexcept` after method declaration :

> In C++11, you generally should use noexcept instead. The old throw specification is deprecated.

How to do it in the following code?

```
template <typename Object>
class Stack
{
public:

    Stack();

    Object & peek() throw(std::runtime_error);

};
```

Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352927/)

Please avoid linking to the questions which do not work for `std::runtime_error`

Comment: This is not noexcept.  Simply remove the throw clause, or make it a comment..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between C++03 throw() specifier C++11 noexcept](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833241/difference-between-c03-throw-specifier-c11-noexcept)

Comment: @m0nhawk how does this link deal with `std::runtime_error`?

Comment: @barej, *noexcept was added because it's the one reasonably useful use of an exception specifier: knowing when a function won't throw an exception. Thus it becomes a binary choice: functions that will throw and functions that won't throw.* You have comments for communicating when you'll throw which types.

Comment: @chris  so do you mean `throw` can set what to strop throwing while `noexcept` cannot?

Comment: @barej, Yes, only `throw` checks for specific exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was found that dynamic exception specifications were not really useful, which is why they've been deprecated in C++11.  The only case where they were deemed useful were *empty* dynamic exception specification, that is `throw()`.  For this case, the `noexcept` declaration was introduced as a better alternative, allowing the compiler to perform more aggressive optimizations.  (Note that this means that `throw()` and `noexcept` are *not* semantically equivalent and you should only replace the former with the latter if you know that the program will still behave correctly.)

In your case, you don't have an empty `throw()` so you cannot replace it with `noexcept`.  It is widely agreed upon that in this case, it would be best to simply remove the `throw(std::runtime_error)` and mention the fact that the function might throw a `std::runtime_error` but nothing else in the documentation, as [Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk) has already suggested in the comments.